# How to italicise text in zsh prompt?

Tags: zsh, prezto

I'm struggling to understand how to italicise a section of my zsh prompt (using prezto).

My prompt currently looks like this:

`PROMPT='%F{yellow}%T %F{magenta}${SSH_TTY:+%n@%m }%F{cyan}%1~%f${vcs_info}\
 55 %(!.%B%F{red}#%f%b.%B %(?.%F{green}.%F{red})❯%f%b) '`

Say I wanted to make the vcs_info italic, how would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory, the ANSI escape code `\e[3m` sets the italic [SGR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#graphics). So to answer your question, this should work:

```
PROMPT='...%{\x1b[3m%}${vcs_info}%{\x1b[0m...%}'
```

Unfortunately, *`italic text`* is [not widely supported in terminals emulators](https://superuser.com/questions/204743/terminal-that-supports-the-ansi-italic-escape-code). Some just ignore it, others inverse the colors instead of italicizing text. To test your terminal emulator, check the output of `echo -e "\e[3mitalic\e[0m"`. If that doesn't print *`italic`*, you need to use a terminal emulator that does, such as gnome-terminal.