# How to italicize prompt for zsh (oh-my-zsh, iTerm2)?

Tags: zsh, prompt, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

I want to italicize my prompt (specifically the right prompt/RPROMPT) for zsh using oh-my-zsh, in iTerm2, and so far have had problems doing so. I have checked that the terminal can output and view italicized fonts with `echo -e "\e[3mitalic\e[0m"`.

Things I have tried so far :

1. `RPROMPT = '\e[3m Hello \e[0m'` : the output is a literal quote `\e[3m Hello \e[0m`
2. from [here](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/issues/6214), I tried

```
 HELLO = Hello
 RPROMPT = '\e[3m $Hello \e[0m'`
```

and the output still has the `\e[3m` and `\e[0m` parts

3. from [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35407320/how-to-italicise-text-in-zsh-prompt), I tried using `\x1b[3m` rather than `\e[3m` : still outputs `\x1b[3m` and `\x1b[0m`
4. I found [this page](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting/issues/432) but I don't understand what I'm looking at/what I'm supposed to do.

I would like to get the italic format working, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you, the dollar sign in front was exactly what I needed! Do you want to turn your comment into an answer, and I'll mark this as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `RPROMPT=$'string with special escaping'` ([See bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html))

It may have a few issues such as the left prompt getting edited.

Comment: Based on your answer, I managed to find a solution that does not mess with the left prompt. You need to use a string quote ```%{ ... %}``` to wrap around the escape sequence formatting, e.g. ```RPROMPT=$'%{\x1b[3m%} hello %{\x1b[0m%}'```

Answer (score 1):

For better compatibility (in case you run your zsh one day with a different kind of `TERM`), I would not hard-code the escape sequences, but use something like

```
RPROMPT="$(tput sitm) Hello $(tput sgr0)"
```

See *man terminfo* for the meaning of `sitm` and `sgr0`.

Answer (score 0):

After further testing based on GrapeApple's answer, I found a solution that does not mess with the left prompt. Per [zsh documentation](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html), you need to use a string quote `%{ ... %}` to wrap around the escape sequence formatting, e.g. :

`RPROMPT=$'%{\x1b[34;1;3m%} hello %{\x1b[0m%}'`